# An instructor wants to create an exam consisting of 5 questions and covering 6 chapters of the textbook....

Tags: probability

An instructor wants to create an exam consisting of $5$ questions and covering $6$ chapters of the textbook. To this end, he first makes up $10$ questions from each of the $6$ chapters, and then selects at random $5$ different questions from these $60$ questions

(a) What is the probability that the questions on the exam are all from
different chapters (i.e., that no chapter has more than one question on the exam)?

---

First I tried to get the total number of outcomes.

There are $60$ questions and only $5$ of them will be used. Since order of the questions don't matter $$|S| = {60\choose5}$$

Secondly I have to get the number of outcomes that the questions are all different chapters.

$10A + 10B + 10C + 10D + 10E$. There are $6$ chapters and $10$ questions each so I labeled the chapters A to E where $A$ is chapter $1$ and so on.

I have no idea how to go about this could please explain carefully

Answer (score 2):

Number of ways to get the desired result:

Number of ways to pick first question $=60$. Second question $=50$. Third $=40$. Fourth $=30$. Fifth $=20$. Total number of ways to pick $5$ questions from different chapters $=60.50.40.30.20$

Total number of ways to pick $5$ questions at random $=60.59.58.57.56$

Divide to get the desired probability.

Answer (score 1):

you select one question from each chapter and select five chapters out of six and the probability goes something like this.  This is another way.

$$ = \frac{{10\choose1}^5{6\choose5}}{{60\choose5}} = \frac{600000.120}{60.59.58.57.56} = 0.10986$$